# How to get notified when iPhone battery is at 10%

Tags: swift, notifications, watchkit, apple-watch, battery

I'm building an Apple Watch app that let you see the `iPhone` battery level,
This is the code to get the battery level:

```
 UIDevice.currentDevice().batteryMonitoringEnabled = true
 batteryLevel = UIDevice.currentDevice().batteryLevel
```

Now how can I call a notification when the `iPhone` battery is at 10%?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is Objective-C but easily translated to Swift:

```
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES];
    float battery = [[UIDevice currentDevice] batteryLevel];

    if (battery < alertLevel) {
        //Send notification   
    }
```

How to send a UILocalNotification

```
        UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        notification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
        notification.alertBody = @"WARNING!";
        notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
        NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Low battery!" forKey:@"Notification"];
        notification.userInfo = infoDict;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```